# D3 transition not working...at all

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

Im new to d3 and having a problem with transitions. I have a dendrogram graph that. This bit of code applies the paths to the nodes.

```
var link = g.selectAll(".link")
    .data(root.descendants().slice(1))
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        return "M" + radialPoint(d.x, d.y)
            + "C" + radialPoint(d.x, (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2)
            + " " + radialPoint(d.parent.x, (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2)
            + " " + radialPoint(d.parent.x, d.parent.y);
      })
      .transition(t);
```

This bit is a function that applies the transition attributes.

```
  var t = d3.transition()
    .delay(1000)
    .duration(1000);
```

Not sure where i'm going wrong with applying the transition but nothing happens when the paths are populated. No transitional effect at all.

If you can spot the issue I would be grateful for the help. Thanks!

Comment: What attribute(s) are you transitioning? Currently the code is set up so that nothing transitions - the code chained to d3.transition() needs to specify what happens, currently only a delay and transition period are specified. What attributes do you want to transition?

Comment: You are transitioning to **nothing**.

Comment: I want the graph to ease in when it loads. Im not really sure how to specify what I'm transitioning to.